# onload for JS Function with Java in it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, jsp

I am trying to use this:

```
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Termine");

window.onload = function(){
<%
    while(rs1.next()){ 
    String vname = rs1.getString(1);
    String vid = rs1.getString(2);
    System.out.println(vid+" "+vname);%>
    document.getElementById(<%=vid%>).innerHTML="<%=vname%>";
    <%
    }
```

But it's not working.The Results of the ResultSet are printed out immediately (whats there for test purposes), but FireBug says: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`.  The Element is a `<td>`, which is created in the Body of the JSP Page. What can i do to get it working, right when i want it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lel, The Solution was:
document.getElementById("<%=vid%>").innerHTML="<%=vname%>";
The Double Quotes for vid were missing.